# Can a Canadian citizen teach English in Iran?

Tags: visa, working-visas, canadian-citizens

If it's possible I would like to teach English in Iran. I am a 22 year old male Canadian citizen with a TEFL certification who has never been to Israel (Or anywhere close to the Middle East).

I understand that I must be sponsored with a work Visa. However relations between the two countries have been better, and Iran's economy is not in good shape.

[Website resources for 'out there' jobs related to travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/website-resources-for-out-there-jobs-related-to%20-travel)

Searching for Iran in the links above gives me nothing, are there any places or forums where I can get in contact with someone willing to sponsor me, or am I simply out of luck?

Comment: Why are you specifically choosing Iran? If you know someone here, they should be able to help you much much more as a local.

Comment: From a friend who just started working there I heard that Iran is quite strict in filling jobs from abroad: if locals can fill the job, employers are not allowed to contract foreigners. But teaching English might just fulfill that criterium ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would like to say it was the worst idea I have ever heard — considering Canada has not an embassy in Iran and there has been a lot of false detentions of Canadian citizens during the past decade.

Secoundly, yes, you need a work permit visa and to acquire one you need to negotiate with an employer, and there is not a job bank website on the internet for Iran so you would be able to search them there, because, you are doing some thing bizarre!

Hence, you need to search potential employer’s website one by one;there is pretty good chance they would more than welcome you and you earn good money if you are good at teaching.

Comment: *there has been a lot of false detentions of Canadian citizens during the past decade.* References, please?

Comment: @JanDoggen I am afraid there is no document, research or statement that I can refer to, But I live in Iran and I am the reference in this case. Sorry I can not provide any proof for organized governmental political activities.